# Como fazer um Insert com condições no SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-insert

Estou tentando fazer um insert, sendo que uma coluna depende de um resultado

```
INSERT INTO TABELA (ID, (CASE 'opcao1'
                             WHEN 'opcao1' THEN "campo1"
                             WHEN 'opcao2' THEN "campo2"
                             ELSE campo3
                         END))
VALUES ('11'),'20')
```

Comment: De qual resultado? Pode explicar melhor a dúvida? Bem vindo ao StackOverflow, recomendo a leitura no [tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender um pouco mais sobre o funcionamento do site.

Comment: isso me parece uma baita gambiarra =]

Comment: Olá, minha sugestão é fazer essa lógica no código.

Comment: Qual engine de SQL?

Comment: Tente explicar o porque está fazendo isso, pode ter outras ideias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sugiro duas formas de fazer:

**Forma 1** - Condição no select

Neste caso seu insert sempre será declarado com todos os campos, e no lugar do values, você usará uma consulta condicionada.

```
DECLARE @opcao VARCHAR(10) = 'opcao3'

INSERT INTO TABELA (ID, CAMPO1, CAMPO2, CAMPO3)
SELECT 11, CASE @opcao WHEN 'opcao1' THEN 20 ELSE NULL END 'Campo1'
         , CASE @opcao WHEN 'opcao2' THEN 20 ELSE NULL END 'Campo2'
         , CASE @opcao WHEN 'opcao3' THEN 20 ELSE NULL END 'Campo3'
```

**Forma 2** - Executando uma query personalizada

**Compatibilidades**
O `execute` está disponível no SQL Server 2008 em diante.
No Oracle, temos o comando `execute immediate`, disponível a partir do 10g Release 2 (10.2).

Já nesta forma, você precisará montar uma string com sua query montando o insert exatamente como necessita.

```
DECLARE @opcao VARCHAR(10) = 'opcao3'
DECLARE @cmd VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @cmd = 'INSERT INTO TABELA (ID, '+ CASE @opcao
                                            WHEN 'opcao1' THEN 'campo1'
                                            WHEN 'opcao2' THEN 'campo2'
                                            ELSE 'campo3'
                                            END +')'+
            ' VALUES (''11'', ''20'')'
EXECUTE(@cmd)
```

Comment: este método é exclusivo do SQL Server 2008 pra frente não é? Acho que seria bom identificar isso, só para complementar

Comment: Obrigado @Dudaskank por me atentar a isto. Já atualizei a resposta.